# If $p$ and $q$ are two primes greater than $3$ then prove that $24 \mid p^2-q^2$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are two primes greater than $3$ then prove that $24\mid p^2-q^2$ .
My solution goes like this:

> If $p,q$ are primes greater than $3$ then $8 \mid p^2-q^2$ as any odd perfect square is of the form $8k+1$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ . Now, $p\equiv 1,2 \pmod{3}$ and $q\equiv 1,2\pmod{3}$ ($0 $ cant be a case as $p,q$ are primes). So, we see that all possible combinations in the remainders of $p,q$ will be equivalent to zero either by doing $p+q$ or  by $p-q$ such that $3 \mid p^2-q^2$ . So, $24 \mid p^2-q^2$.

I just want to verify whether my solution is okay or not.

Comment: The first part, about the divisibility by $8$, is ok. As to the second part, just note that  $p^{2} \equiv 1 \equiv q^{2} \pmod{3}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yeah but then again $ p^2-q^2\equiv 0(mod 3) $ holds true....so that shouldn't be a problem ....

Comment: This question has appeared many times on this site...the duplicate I linked to is itself a duplicate.

Comment: @lulu No..actually i wanted to verify my solution ...

Comment: As I think you'll see, your argument matches the arguments that appear in the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

$p^2,q^2 \mod 24 \equiv 1$ for $p,q>3$

since $p^2 =(p-1)(p+1)+1$ where both of $(p-1)$ and $(p+1)$ are divisible by $2$, either one is divisible by $3$ and one by $4$ respectively.

Thus, their difference $p^2-q^2 \mod 24 \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is right, but by dividing your solution with parts, you can arrange it so you can read it easily.

\begin{align}
& \text{STEP 1. } 3 | p^2-q^2. \\
& p, q > 3 \Rightarrow p^2 \equiv q^2 \equiv 1(\text{mod } 3). \\
\therefore \; & p^2-q^2 \equiv 0(\text{mod } 3). \\
\ \\
& \text{STEP 2. } 8|p^2-q^2. \\
& p, q > 3 \Rightarrow p, q: 8k\pm1 \text{ or } 8k\pm 3. \\
\therefore \; & p^2 \equiv q^2 \equiv 1 (\text{mod } 8). \\
\therefore \; & p^2-q^2 \equiv 0(\text{mod } 8). \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & 24 | p^2-q^2.
\end{align}